# Newlines not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, newline, line-breaks

I'm passing text to JavaScript but the newlines `%0A` gets not interpreted, results in all text is displayed in one line.

URL:

```
https://www.example.com/post.php?v=1&text=hello%0Aworld%0Atest
```

Code:

```
<?php
$postText = $_GET["text"]; 
?>  

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var options = {
        prefilltext: '<?php echo $postText;?>',
      };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried `nl2br` and  `str_replace` without any succes:

```
$postText = str_replace("%0A", "\n", $postText);
$postText = nl2br($postText);
```

What do I need to change to make newlines work?

Answer (score 2):

Just dumping out the text won't work, as you're outputting within a JavaScript string literal.

The simplest way to do this is just use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
  var options = {
    prefilltext: <?php echo json_encode($postText);?>
  };
```

Note no quotes, it will add them.

Why `json_encode` when outputing a string to include in JavaScript? Because [JSON](http://json.org) is a subset of JavaScript syntax, and so any valid JSON is also valid JavaScript source code (provided it's where an expression is expected, such as the right-hand side of an assignment). If `$postText` is a PHP string, `json_encode($postText)` will return the text of a JSON string literal, which can be used as a JavaScript string literal.

---

Side note: Your code also had a dangling comma after the property initializer, e.g.:

```
  var options = {
    prefilltext: 'the text would be here',
    // This is the dangling comma -------^
  };
```

...which I've removed, because [older versions of IE will choke](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/literal-improvement.html) on it